# Retrieve public key from ssh prompt

Tags: ssh, git

In order to add a shell account to my authenticated github acc list, I need to retrieve it's public SSH key; how can I do that either in putty, or via bash directly?

Comment: Have you created a public key in that shell account? Do you remember giving the file a particular name then, or did you simply use the default?

Comment: This question may be better suited on superuser.com (though I don't have the rep required to initiate a migration).

Comment: The server in question is in company's property; so at least I'm hitting the bottom-end of ServerFault's minimal requirements against questions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a key.  This key will be unique to your account.  I'd suggest you take a look at: http://pkeck.myweb.uga.edu/ssh/

Here is an excerpt from that site:

> ```
> ssh-keygen -t dsa
> ```
>
> This will prompt you
>   for a secret passphrase. If this is
>   your primary identity key, make sure
>   to use a good passphrase. If this
>   works right you will get two files
>   called id_dsa and id_dsa.pub in your
>   .ssh dir. Note: it is possible to just
>   press the enter key when prompted for
>   a passphrase, which will make a key
>   with no passphrase. This is a Bad Idea
>   ™ for an identity key, so don't do it!
>   See below for uses of keys without
>   passphrases.

The id_dsa.pub file is what you are after.

Comment: In my understanding, my SSH prompt already have a key -the one I'm using to access the bash prompt? And I figure, this is what GIT uses by default -so I don't have to configure a new one for it

Comment: Well, whatever it is a Bad Idea or not to create a ssh key without a passphrase large depends on what the key is meant to do.

Comment: Yes, I think in this case, making a passphrase-less key may be permissible...but it is worth mentioning in any discussion about creating ssh keys.  And, since it was in the paragraph explaining the command that actually creates the key in the page I quoted, I figured that warning should come along too.

Comment: So, what you are creating is a new key that will be used for authentication.  It actually has nothing to do with your shell (bash in this case).  The SSH client program will use this key when authenticating against a server.